# Aggregate values from selected divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to pass all the values from some selected divs, where the ids of the divs are the values I want to get and aggregate to a textbox, but I'm not getting any result. Basically I want the `id` from a `div`, in for example `div id="thisOne"` when I click. My script looks like this:

```
<script>
function myFunction(elmnt, clr) {
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = clr;
    document.getElementById("allValues").value = document.getElementById(elmnt.value).value;
}
</script>
```

VIEW:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?=base_url()?>index.php/dashboard/test_val">
                <div id="frame">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php 
                        for($i = 0, $size = count($farm)-1; $i < $size; $i++) {
                            if($i == 0) 
                                echo '<tr>';

                            if($flag == 1){
                                echo '</tr>';
                                echo '<tr>';
                                $flag = 0;
                            }
                            if($farm[$i]['id_field'] == $farm[$i+1]['id_field']) {
                                echo '<td>';?>
                                <div id="<?php echo $farm[$i]['section_name'] ?>" onclick="myFunction(this, 'red')" style="width:60px; height:60px; border:1px solid #aaaaaa;background:#CCFF99">
                                <center><?php echo $farm[$i]['section_name'] ?></center></div>
                                <?php echo '</td>';
                            }else
                                $flag = 1;

                            if($i == $size - 1)
                                echo '</tr>';
                        }?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div>
                    <label>Select fertilizer to aplly:</label>
                    <select name="ChoosenFert">
                        <?php foreach ($fertilization as $row) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"> <?php echo $row['type'] ?> </option>                      
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    </select>
                    <br /> 
                    <button>Apply Fertilizer</button>
                    <input type="text" id="allValues" name="allValues" hidden>
                </div>
            </form>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function test_val(){
        $inputData = $this->input->post("allValues");
        echo $inputData;
    }
```

Comment: Why they keep adding `PHP` code instead of `HTML`

Comment: HTML AND JAVASCRIPT OR JQUERY CODE NEEDED ?

Comment: html and jquery needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("allValues").value += elmnt.id;
```

in your function "myFunction".